# c# - How to get network adapter name in a combobox or list?

Tags: c#, class, combobox, network-programming

I'm a beginner programmer and i'm making a small winform application to change my IP address quickly (from DHCP to STATIC). I'm using netsh commands.

I'm struggling with getting the name of the network adapters and add it in a combobox. So far, I've only added this line at the beggining of the program :

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

I tried this line of code but it returns only one adapter name :

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) 
{ 
    value = nic.Name; 
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Are there multiple network “adapters” on the computer?

Comment: Well, you are assigning all the names to the very same variable, so no matter how many there are it will look like one. Add them to a List<string> instead!

Comment: If @TaW is correct debugging your own code could have solved the mystery easiliy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TaW, I finally ended up with this :

```
List<string> AdapterList = new List<string>();
            foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                AdapterList.Add(nic.Name);
            }
            networkAdapterList.DataSource = AdapterList;
```

It works perfectly fine !